# Not reading C++ input

Tags: c++

I have only a little experience in C++. I'm trying to write a program to print each element of the 'sales' array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
void printArray(int, int);

int main()
{
    char chips[5][50] = {"mild", "medium", "sweet", "hot", "zesty"};
    int sales[5] = {0};

    int tempSales, counter;
    const int i = 5;

    for (counter = 0; counter < i; counter++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter in the sales for " << chips[counter] << ": ";
        cin >> tempSales;

        tempSales >> sales[counter][5];
    }

    cout << "{";
    for (int counter = 0; counter < i; counter++)
    {
        cout << chips[counter] << ", ";
    }
    cout << "}" << endl;

    cout << "{";
    for (int counter = 0; counter < i; counter++)
    {
        cout << sales[counter] << ", ";
    }
    cout << "}" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

To solve this problem, I need to have the same commands and keywords I still have, and it can't be any advanced or weird syntax. For some reason, my input from the:

```
    cin >> tempSales
```

Is not functioning. Here are the results:

```
{mild, medium, sweet, hot, zesty, }
{0,0,0,0,0, }
```

Whereas I just want to see 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 for the second array. Why is it only print 0 and not reading my input? Please help!

Comment: Why do you need a 2D array to store sales ? `int sales[5][6] = {0};` was this intended ? should it be just `int sales[5] = {0};` ?

Comment: `char chips[5][50] = {"mild", "medium", "sweet", "hot", "zesty"};` -- Why not simply use an array of `std::string`? `std::string chips[] = {"mild", "medium", "sweet", "hot", "zesty"};`.  You mention "weird syntax", but using two dimensional char arrays instead of `std::string` would be considered weird.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a 2D array for sales. Try `cout << sales[counter][5] << ", ";` or change `int sales[5][6] = {0};` to `int sales[5] = {0};`. As Luke mentioned, use standard assignment `sales[counter] = tempSales;`.

Comment: Well I fixed that, but the results stayed the same. What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Like rranjik stated, you shouldn't need a 2D array if you're only listing the number of sales, which it appears you're doing from what you provided, is this not the case?

Is it necessary for you to use the bitshift operator `>>` for your assignment? For a simple integer assignment it isn't really necessary, and you could do:

`int sales[5] = {0};` Change the array to a simple array instead of 2D.

`sales[counter] = tempSales;` Use standard assignment for the integer on line 19

`cout << sales[counter] << ", ";` Change your output accordingly.

Hope this helps!